# vb PrintDocument not printing within specified margins

Tags: vb.net, printing, margin

I am using the following code to print but every time I print to a laser printer, the right and bottom margins get cut off regardless of what I set my margins at. Could anyone shed some light on this situation? Note, I have tried using `PrintDoc.OriginAtMargins = True/False` but it doesn't appear to be working either.

/code/

```
Public MarginSize As Integer = 15

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    'temp = Nothing

    'With dgView
    '    For Each row In dgView.Rows
    '        temp += row.Cells(0).Value & "   " & row.Cells(1).Value & "   " & row.Cells(2).Value & "   " & row.Cells(3).Value & vbNewLine
    '    Next
    'End With

    PrintDialog.PrinterSettings = PrintDoc.PrinterSettings

    If PrintDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        PrintDoc.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog.PrinterSettings

        Dim PageSetup As New PageSettings

        With PageSetup
            .Margins.Left = MarginSize
            .Margins.Right = MarginSize
            .Margins.Top = MarginSize
            .Margins.Bottom = MarginSize
            .Landscape = False
        End With

        PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings = PageSetup

    End If

    ' PrintDoc.OriginAtMargins = False

    PrintPreviewDialog.Document = PrintDoc
    PrintPreviewDialog.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    PrintPreviewDialog.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1
    PrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDoc_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc.PrintPage

    Static intStart As Integer
    Dim fntText As Font = txtDrawnBy.Font
    Dim txtHeight As Integer
    Dim LeftMargin As Integer = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
    Dim RightMargin As Integer = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - MarginSize
    Dim TopMargin As Integer = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
    Dim BottomMargin As Integer = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - MarginSize

    txtHeight = PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top - PrintDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom

    Dim LinesPerPage As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(txtHeight / (fntText.Height + 0.025)))

    'Draw Rectangle for Margin
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, e.MarginBounds)

    Dim y1 As Integer = e.PageBounds.Height.ToString / 3
    Dim y2 As Integer = e.PageBounds.Height.ToString / 3 * 2

    'Draw line 1/4 way down
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Orange, LeftMargin, y1, RightMargin, y1)

    'Draw line 3/4 way down
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Orange, LeftMargin, y2, RightMargin, y2)

    Dim intLineNumber As Integer
    Dim sf As New StringFormat
    Dim LineStep As Integer = 0

    For intCounter = intStart To 66

        'Print line numbers
        e.Graphics.DrawString(intLineNumber.ToString & ": ", fntText, Brushes.Black, LeftMargin, fntText.Height * intLineNumber + TopMargin)

        intLineNumber += 1
        If intLineNumber > LinesPerPage Then
            intStart = intCounter
            e.HasMorePages = True
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

I have also attached an image of my results.
[Image of print results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k64RG.png)

Comment: Maybe the paper size in your printer settings doesn't match the paper that you use with printer.

Comment: You did not set PageSettings.PaperSize.  Odds that you loaded the correct paper size into the printer are iffy, zero if it is cut-off.

Comment: I added `.PaperSize = New PaperSize("Letter", 850, 1100)` and it still cuts off the right and bottom.

Comment: Looks like I a confined to the print area of 802x1066 is there a way to override the print area so that I can print outside of the print area?

Comment: Is it an hp printer ?

Comment: Yes, it is an HP Laser Jet P3015